# How to add values by using a sequence in plsql if only the field is null?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, procedure

I need to add values for a number field and if only it is null, then I have to add a number by using a sequence. I have created the code for this. But since this field is a unique field
I can't add duplicate values. For example as the first record if I entered number 1 and in the next record if I not pass a value for that field, it will automatically generate a value and if its equals to a old record number its showing an error like record already exists. Can someone help me to solve this.

```
PROCEDURE InsertValues(
newrec_ IN OUT myTable%ROWTYPE,
indrec_ IN OUT Indicator_Rec,
attr_   IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
BEGIN

IF(newrec_.id IS null) then
newrec_.id := myTable_id.NEXTVAL;

Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('ID', newrec_.id, attr_);

END IF;
super(newrec_, indrec_, attr_);

END InsertValues;
```

Comment: you can't have it both ways.   Just always use a sequence value and don't let the caller choose a value.  If the caller needs to know the ID, then return myTable_id.currval.

Comment: If you're updating existing data, you'll have to set the starting value of your sequence to something higher than any of the existing values in the table, then use the sequence exclusively (no user input) for that field going forward.